# How to restart network in ubuntu server 14.04.04？

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface, ifconfig

I tried using `service network restart` and `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, what command could I use now?

Comment: Please add what happened when you executed those commands and what you expected instead.

Comment: service network restart
network: unrecognized service

Comment: What is the output of `service --status-all 2>&1 | grep network`

Comment: only one:  [ ? ]  networking

Comment: I'm curious if you are seeing this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1301015

Answer (score 3):

Ifdown ethx ; ifup ethx

Should do it

"service networking restart" isnt working in ubuntu, because other services are dependent on it, theres a more complete answer here  https://askubuntu.com/questions/561046/why-is-service-networking-restart-not-working-in-14-04

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Network-Manager so that would use:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

When in doubt try:

```
sudo ifdown <interface>
sudo ifup <interface>
```

That should work, if doing this over ssh combine the commands:

```
sudo ifdown <interface> && sudo ifup <interface>
```

Give that a try.

Looks like this issue is related to the following:

http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1301015

Comment: service network-manager restart
network-manager: unrecognized service

Comment: I changed dns server,it didn't work

Comment: Did you try: sudo service network-manager restart

Comment: Yes，but that‘s server edition，could not find network-mamager